# Spring Boot AMQP unable to do a SSL connection

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using a Springboot application to connect to RabbitMQ server. The connection 
was working fine but then the server changed the port to SSL enabled.

I added a property

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled: true
```

It worked for sometime but now  getting below exception

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Any idea, what I am missing here ?

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem?i'm trying to connect my springboot app to a 5671 port but i can't

Comment: Yes, spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled: true worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same exception. In my case, by mistake I was using the below mentioned property for mentioning the rabbitmq host.

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=hosturl
spring.rabbitmq.port=5671
```

Then I updated the above property with the below one and it is working fine:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=hostURL
spring.rabbitmq.port=5671
```

spring.rabbitmq.addresses- if you are using this then make sure to mention the rabbmitmq url as host:port and comma seperated values for multiple VMs(rabbitmq cluster)